# SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas when using iloc

Tags: python, pandas

The following lines of code gives me the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I have tried applying `.copy()` as suggested in many other answers on this topic, but I cant seem to get the warning to disappear. The line of code which creates the error is the last line where `iloc` is invoked. I can't however understand why this should be a problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100), columns =['col1'])
df['col2']=df.loc[:,'col1'].diff()
df['col2'].iloc[0]=0
```

Can somebody help me understand what creates this warning and what the right syntax would be to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

`df['col2'].iloc[0]=0` uses [chained indexing](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning#chainedassignment) hence the error

1. You index once with `df['col2']`
2. You index a second time with `.loc[0]`

This is frowned upon (and often behaves in unintuitive ways) in pandas. Instead consider the following "correct" ways of doing the same thing:

```
df.loc[0,'col2'] = 0
df.at[0,'col2'] = 0
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('col2')] = 0
```

Or consider

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```